# DynamoDB - how to get Primary Key (which is random id) from database to make endpoind class?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, primary-key

I've made method that I use to edit Item from database.
This is how my method looks:

```
public Product editProduct(PrimaryKey primaryKey, Product content) {

    UpdateItemSpec updateItemSpec = new UpdateItemSpec().withPrimaryKey(primaryKey).withValueMap(createValueMap(content));

    UpdateItemOutcome itemOutcome = databaseController.getTable(PRODUCT_TABLE).updateItem(updateItemSpec);

    return  convertToProduct(itemOutcome);

}

private Map<String, Object> createValueMap(Product content) {

    Map<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();

    result.put("name", content.getName());
    result.put("calories", content.getCalories());
    result.put("fat", content.getFat());
    result.put("carbo", content.getCarbo());
    result.put("protein", content.getProtein());
    result.put("productKinds", content.getProductKinds());
    result.put("author", content.getAuthor());
    result.put("media", content.getMedia());
    result.put("approved", content.getApproved());

    return result;
}

private Product convertToProduct(UpdateItemOutcome itemOutcome) {

    Product product = new Product();
    product.setName(itemOutcome.getItem().get("name").toString());
    product.setCalories(itemOutcome.getItem().getInt("calories"));
    product.setFat(itemOutcome.getItem().getDouble("fat"));
    product.setCarbo(itemOutcome.getItem().getDouble("carbo"));
    product.setProtein(itemOutcome.getItem().getDouble("protein"));
    product.setProductKinds(itemOutcome.getItem().getList("productKinds"));

    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try {
        Author productAuthor = objectMapper.readValue(itemOutcome.getItem().getString("author"), Author.class);
        product.setAuthor(productAuthor);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        Media productMedia = objectMapper.readValue(itemOutcome.getItem().getString("media"), Media.class);
        product.setMedia(productMedia);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return product;

}
```

Now I want to create endpoint class for this method but I have problem, I need to get primarykey as parameter (it's looks like this for example: 2567763a-d21e-4146-8d61-9d52c2561fc0) and I don't know how to do this.

At the moment my class looks like that:

```
public class EditProductLambda implements RequestHandler<Map<String, Object>, ApiGatewayResponse> {
private LambdaLogger logger;
@Override
public ApiGatewayResponse handleRequest(Map<String, Object> input, Context context) {
    logger = context.getLogger();
    logger.log(input.toString());

    try{
        Product product = RequestUtil.parseRequest(input, Product.class);
        //PrimaryKey primaryKey = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
        KitchenService kitchenService = new KitchenService(new DatabaseController(context, Regions.EU_CENTRAL_1), logger);
        Product editedProduct = kitchenService.editProduct(primaryKey, product);
        return ResponseUtil.generateResponse(HttpStatus.SC_CREATED, editedProduct);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e){
        return ResponseUtil.generateResponse(HttpStatus.SC_BAD_REQUEST, e.getMessage());

    }


}
```

Can someone give me some advice how to do that? Or maybe my method is done wrong?

Comment: Are you using API gateway and Lambda?

Comment: Yes it's EditProductLambda class that I need to create endpoind and in this class I don't know how to get PrimaryKey

Comment: ok. How do you want to pass primary key? As query string or as a body in POST request?

Comment: which way in Your opinion would be better?

Comment: You can use either. If it is a GET ideally query string. If POST request body. I have added an answer

Comment: Yeah but look at my Lambda class, there is in try{} something like that: //PrimaryKey primaryKey = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
and I dunno what to do with this, i need it to use editProduct method

Answer (score 0):

So first you have to create a trigger to Lambda function and ideal prefer here would be an API gateway. You can pass your data as query string or as a request body to API gateway.

You can use body mapping template in the integration request section of API gateway and get request body/query string. Construct a new json at body mapping template, which will have data from request body/query string. As we are adding body mapping template your business logic will get the json we have constructed at body mapping template.

Inside body mapping template to get query string please do ,

$input.params('querystringkey')

For example inside body mapping template (If using query string),

```
#set($inputRoot = $input.path('$'))
{
"primaryKey" : "$input.params('$.primaryKey')"
}
```

if passing data as body then,

```
#set($inputRoot = $input.path('$'))
{
"primaryKey" : "$input.path('$.primaryKey')"
}
```

Please read https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/tag/mapping-templates/ for more details on body mapping template